# Determining Place Of Student using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a studentResult table in which a column name is TotalMarks where students total marks is given..I have to determine the place of studnents(i.e 1st, 2nd,3rd,4th etc..) on the base of the TotalMarks they get in examination.How I can determine this using store procedure in SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 3):

Guessing, based on no description of schema, whether a student is in one row or represented multiple times, what to do in the case of ties, etc.

```
SELECT
    StudentID, Name, TotalMarks,
    Place = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalMarks DESC)
FROM
    dbo.StudentResult
ORDER BY
    TotalMarks DESC;
```

Comment: +1 - Though I think that in this case `RANK` is a better fit

Comment: @Lamak you may be right. But with such vague specs, who knows... could be `DENSE_RANK()` too.